# What is the probability (is my solution correct? If not solve it please)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Probability that a shooter hits the mark with a shot is 0,78. Find the probability if from five shots the shooter hits the mark at least two times.
My solution is: Let D: the event that it hits the mark at least rwi times and E: the shooter hits the mark only one time and B: the shooter never hits the mark (1-0,78) then: P(D)=1-P(B)-P(E) =1-(0.22)^5 - (5)(0,78)(0,22)^4 its multiple by 5 cuz there are 5 possibilities to choose one shot .

Comment: Yes approach is correct. Find that shooter never hits the target or hits the target only once and then subtract from $1$. But where is your working? There is no way to validate unless you add your working.

Comment: Isnt given but it can be found  by taking P(2times)=(5 2) (0,78)^2(0,22)^3      (5 2) is combination

Comment: Sure, approach is ok.

Comment: I edited the question that tells  all the work. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming shots are independent, let the number $X$ of hits in $n = 5$ shots be
distributed $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=5,\, p = 0.78).$ You seek $P(X\ge 2) = 1 - P(X\le 1).$ In R statistical software, where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF, this can be computed as follows:

```
1 - pbinom(1, 5, 0.78) 
[1] 0.9903487
```

Or you can use the formula for the binomial PDF:

$$1 - P(X=0) - P(X=1) = 1 - (1-.78)^5 + 5(.78)(1-.78)^4 = 0.9903487.$$

```
p = 0.78; 1 - (1-p)^5 - 5*p*(1-p)^4
[1] 0.9903487
```